# Can't verify captor in Mockito

Tags: android, mockito, verify

Wrote next test:

```
private val mockContext = Mockito.mock(Context::class.java)
private val notificationManager = Mockito.mock(NotificationManager::class.java)

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun clearNotificationsTest() {
    Mockito.`when`(mockContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).thenReturn(notificationManager)

    val captor: ArgumentCaptor<NotificationChannel> = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(NotificationChannel::class.java)

    mockContext.registerNotificationChannels()

    Mockito.verify(notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(captor.capture()))

    val argument: NotificationChannel = captor.value

    assertThat(argument.id, equalTo(CHANNEL_ID))
    assertThat(argument.name.toString(), equalTo(CHANNEL_NAME))
    assertThat(argument.importance, equalTo(NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_HIGH))
}
```

And get next error in my `verify`:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:
>   Argument passed to verify() is of type Unit and is not a mock!
>   Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
>   See the examples of correct verifications:
>   verify(mock).someMethod();
>   verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
>   verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();

Comment: What is that test supposed to do? For me it locks like you only call methods on mocks (mockContext & notificationManager), so you are not testing anything here ...

Comment: and the Syntax for verify should be Mockito.verify(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(captor.capture()), assuming you want to verify some interaction with the createNotificationChannel method. But there is most likely none, as calling  `mockContext.registerNotificationChannels()` does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you write verify using mock

```
Mockito.verify(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(captor.capture()));
```

Comment: Why? I wrote that it was in this line that I received an error, which I also pointed out in the question

Comment: Mockito.verify(notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(captor.capture())) this is what you have on your code but it should be like Mockito.verify(notificationManager).createNotificationChannel(captor.capture()));

Answer (score 0):

How did you define

```
notificationManager
```

Using MockitoAnnotations you can define a field as follows in your test

```
@Mock
NotificationManager notificationManager

@Before
public void setup()
{
   MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
}
```

**NOTE:** to spy on a class it must either be a mock or a **real** object that has been spied on. i.e.

```
  val notificationManagerSpy: spy(notificationManager)
```

If you're using a test framework such as [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) you will have a **real** [ShadowNotificationManager](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/shadows/framework/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowNotificationManager.java) therefore you should spy on the real object. The solution would be as follows:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun clearNotificationsTest() 
{
   val notificationManagerSpy: spy(notificationManager)
   Mockito.`when`(mockContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
      .thenReturn(notificationManagerSpy)

    val captor: ArgumentCaptor<NotificationChannel> = 
      ArgumentCaptor.forClass(NotificationChannel::class.java)

    mockContext.registerNotificationChannels()


    Mockito.verify(notificationManagerSpy
    .createNotificationChannel(captor.capture()))

    val argument: NotificationChannel = captor.value

    assertThat(argument.id, equalTo(CHANNEL_ID))
    assertThat(argument.name.toString(), equalTo(CHANNEL_NAME))
    assertThat(argument.importance, 
    equalTo(NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_HIGH))
```

see: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy for more information on spying and what is a valid spyable object.

Comment: I updated the question and showed as I do the plug for `notificationManager`.
Also i didn't use Robolectric